# Does $p=x^2+4y^2$ imply that $x$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

Does $p=x^2+4y^2$ imply that $x$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$?

I'm stuck on this problem. My attempt:

We know that since $p$ is a sum of squares $p\equiv 1 (4)$. This means that $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=1$. Hence we have
$$
x^2\equiv -4y^2\equiv (k2y)^2 (p)
$$
for some $k$ with $k^2\equiv-1(p)$. And hence
$$
x\equiv \pm (k2y) (p)
$$
So we can write
$$
\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)
$$
And since 
$$
\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if }p\equiv 1(8)\\
-1&\text{ if }p\equiv 5(8)\\
\end{cases}
$$
We can reduce to
$$
\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)
$$
i.e. either both $x$ and $y$ are quadratic residues or neither is. Which might be interesting or it might not be; I'm stuck here.

Any input would be appreciated, either telling me where to go from here, or using completely different arguments.

Comment: I assume that, despite "quadric" in the title and the first line of the question, you meant "quadratic".

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already proved that $p=x^2+4y^2$ implies $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Then, by quadratic reciprocity:
$$ \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}\right)=\left(\frac{x^2+4y^2}{x}\right)=\left(\frac{4y^2}{x}\right) = 1 $$
since $4y^2 = (2y)^2$.

Comment: Thanks, that is very nice and easy. You use that $p\equiv 1(4)$ for 
$$\left(\frac{x}{x^2+4y^2}\right)=\left(\frac{x^2+4y^2}{x}\right)$$right? Also, these are Jacobi symbols from the third term on right?

Comment: @user2520938: exactly, due to $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ we may simply swap the "numerator" and "denominator" of the Jacobi symbol when applying quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: And then we'd have to remark that $x$ must be odd since $p$ is, hence the Jacobi symbol is defined, I think?

Comment: @user2520938: sure, but that is quite trivial.

Comment: Agreed, just want to be sure that I get this:p Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user2520938: you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

We work with Legendre symbols only. Note that $x$ is odd. Then $x$ can be expressed as 
$$x=(\pm 1)(q_1q_2\cdots q_k),\tag{1}$$ 
where the $q_i$ are odd primes. We have $(-1/p)=1$. Also, for any $i$, we have $(q_i/p)=(p/q_i)$. But since $q_i$ divides $x$, it follows that $(p/q_i)=((x^2+4y^2)/q_i)=(4y^2/q_i)=1$.

Now we can use the representation (1) to conclude that $(x/p)=1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is really nice too.

Comment: You are welcome. Jacobi symbols are tricky, if we get $-1$ then for sure we have a NR, but if we get $1$ then things can be inconclusive without further argument.